# Should you do an assert statement inside a loop?

Tags: testing

When we have multiple values for which we would like to test a given method should we loop through the values in a single test?

Or is it incorrect as in case of failure it might be harder to identify the cause?

Something like this:

```
testSomething(){
    List myValues = {'value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...}

    for(value: myValues){
        assertTrue(Something(Value))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Not if you can avoid it**

By which I mean, depending on what you're using to do your unit tests, you might not be able to realistically avoid it. In that case, do as needs must

If you run your assert in a loop, you effectively have one test which is testing an arbitrary number of things. That's going to get confusing.

What you want is multiple tests which test one thing each.

Some test frameworks (like NUnit for C#) allow you to define a test that takes parameters and then define the values to repeat the test with.

e.g.

```
[TestCase(1, 1, 2)]
[TestCase(2, 3, 5)]
[TestCase(0, -1, -1)]
public void MyTest(int a, int b, int expected) {        
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, a + b);
}
```

If your framework supports that, it's wonderfully easy to do.

Alternatively, if you're using a script language (e.g. javascript), you might be able to define your tests in a loop, rather than the asserts.

e.g.

```
describe('My tests', function() {
    var testCases = [
        {a: 1, b: 1, expected: 2},
        {a: 2, b: 3, expected: 5},
        {a: 0, b: -1, expected: -1}
    ]

    testCases.forEach(function(t) {
        it(`Adds ${t.a} and ${t.b} correctly`, function() {
            assert.equal(t.expected, t.a + t.b);
        });
    });
})
```

This defines many tests, testing a single thing. Not one test testing many things. Which subsequently makes it much easier to see which one fails when it does.

Comment: I just want to double check, if we must use an assert in a for loop, one or more failed assertions will cause the entire unit test to fail, correct?  I want to make sure that if I have 100,000 items in a list I'm iterating, the first 99,999 asserts fail, but the last one (100,000th) passes, the unit test will still fail, correct?.

Comment: If your asserts are in one test, the test will fail if any assert fails.

Answer (score 4):

**i don't recommend using assertion in loops** (i did it before but then i refactored it). **You can use this instead to provide the same result**:

```
List<String> failedAssertions = new ArrayList<>();

testSomething(){ List myValues = {'value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...}

    for(value: myValues){
        if(!value.equals(somethingActual){
           failedAssertions.add(String.format("Expected: %s, Actual: %s", value, somethingActual));
        }
    }
    assertTrue("Failed assertions: " + String.join(", ", failedAssertions), failedAssertions.isEmpty());
}
```

Your assertion at the end will check only one time if the list empty.

Im late but i would still give a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not directly related to the initial question, but I want to share my approach of implementing several assertions using Kotlin and Junit5.

Sometimes you may have a list of test data you want to check and assert.
There are two obvious ways how to do this: use parametrised tests or use loop.

For some tests it may be not feasible to split them into parametrised tests. I'm not talking about unit tests, but, for example, end to end tests, when each test requires some preparation and it's execution time is pretty large. So you want to run test once, but do several assertions. I'm sure you can imagine such situations.

So, Junit 5 has a very nice method called `assertAll`. It allows you to run several assertions and execution will not stop on the first fail. So you can be sure that all checks were done and you won't miss any.

In general, you have to write assertions manually. For example:

```
assertAll("person",
    { assertEquals("John", person.firstName) },
    { assertEquals("Doe", person.lastName) }
)
```

(taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491377/kotlin-junit-5-assertall-usage)).

But you also can generate assertions using loops (for example using `map`)! It may be very useful, when you have a list of items to check. And here is how you can do it. Simple example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.assertAll

val testItems = listOf(0, 1, 0, 3)
val assertions = testItems.map { testItem ->
    return@map { assertNotEquals(0, testItem, "Test item should not be equal to zero") }
}

assertAll(assertions)
```

Here please don't miss curly braces `{}` around the assertion, so map closure will return you the following data type: `List<() -> Unit>`. This data type perfectly fits to the assertAll() input type.

If you run it, you will get the following error:

```
org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Test item should not be equal to zero ==> expected: not equal but was: <0>
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Test item should not be equal to zero ==> expected: not equal but was: <0>
```

As you can see, both cases that should fail failed.